# How i can scroll using key in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

[image]

i had problem about recyclerview
in that picture blue is recyclerview
and yellow is now focus imageview
when i use keydown, i want scroll down, so want to show green imageview
but it didnt walk

how i can solve it?

main activity is

```
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, this);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    final FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
    layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.CENTER);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

layout is

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and viewholder

```
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        frameLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFlexGrow(1.0f);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add a clicklistener to imageView and use

`layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position);`

Comment: in FlexboxLayoutManager there is no method of scrollToPositionWithOffset();
and how can get position?
can you explain with total code?

Comment: I saw its source code on internet and there was a method like that in there. can you mention the source code here, maybe that wasn't your FlexboxLayoutManager